# Template template parameters with variadic templates

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, template-templates, variadic-functions

For the sake of clarity, I've removed things like the constructor & destructor etc from the below where they don't add anything to the question.  I have a base class that is used to create a common ancestor for a derived template class.

```
class PeripheralSystemBase {
public:
    virtual void someFunctionThatsCommonToAllPeripherals() {}
};

template <class T, uint32_t numPeripherals = 1>
class PeripheralSystem : public PeripheralSystemBase {
public:
    PeripheralSystem() : vec(T) {}
    std::vector<T> vec;  // different types of T is the reason why I need to template this class
};

// A & B declaration & definition are irrelevant here
class A{};
class B{};

// There are multiple different derived variants of PeripheralSystem
// At the moment, each has different template parameters

template <uint32_t customisableParam1>
class DerivedSystem1 : public PeripheralSystem<A, 1> {
public:
    DerivedSystem1() : PeripheralSystem<A, 1>() {}
};

template <uint32_t customisableParam1, uint8_t customisableParam2>
class DerivedSystem2 : public PeripheralSystem<B, 1> {
public:
    DerivedSystem2() : PeripheralSystem<B, 1>() {/*maybe use customisableParam2 here */}
};
```

So now I have 2 templates classes, each derived from the same ancestor class, one containing a vector containing type A, the other of type B; each has different template parameters.  So far, so good.

Now for the question.  I would like to be able to create a container template to contain none, one or more of the derived versions of PeripheralSystem inside it and I think I may be able to use variadic templates to do this, but I've got a bit stuck on the syntax over the past day or so.  At compile time, I'd like to be able to create an instance of the container class.  Perhaps something like:

```
template< template<typename ...> class args...>
class ContainerClass {
  public:
    ContainerClass() : container({args}) {}
    std::vector<PeripheralSystem> container;
};

// possible usage
ContainerClass<DerivedSystem1<1>> cc1;
ContainerClass<DerivedSystem2<2, 3>> cc2;
ContainerClass<DerivedSystem1<1>, DerivedSystem2<2, 3>> cc3;
```

I know the variadic format I'm using isn't right, as I get:

> error: expected ',' or '>' in template-parameter-list template<
>   template class args ...> >

What I'm trying to tell the compiler is that I want to supply a variable number of template-type parameters to the template, each of which has a variable number of template parameters.  Am I able to do this with variadic templates please?  Any suggestions on the correct syntax please?

Comment: are you using C++11 ?

Comment: Yes (in the sense that the compiler switches are set for it). No in the sense that I know how to use it properly, I'm just making the change to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got your ellipsis in the wrong place. Try:

```
template<template<typename...> class... Args>
                                    ^^^ here
```

However, you don't actually want template template parameters; since `DerivedSystem1<1>` is a type, not a template, you just want ordinary typename parameters:

```
template<typename... Args>
class ContainerClass {
```

For the actual container, you can't use `vector<PeripheralSystem>` as that is homogeneous and will slice the derived types down to `PeripheralSystem`. If you add a virtual destructor to `PeripheralSystem` you can use `vector<unique_ptr<PeripheralSystem>>`:

```
template<typename... Args>
class ContainerClass {
  public:
    ContainerClass() : container{std::make_unique<Args>()...} {}
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<PeripheralSystem>> container;
};
```

However, `tuple` would work just as well and result in fewer allocations:

```
template<typename... Args>
class ContainerClass {
  public:
    ContainerClass() : container{Args{}...} {}
    std::tuple<Args...> container;
};
```

Comment: Is there a limit to the max number of elements in a c++11 tuple? Google doesn't appear to be clear - I gather older versions had a limit of 10.

Comment: @John not as such; any older limit would have been from when variadics weren't fully supported. `tuple` should support as many elements as template parameters to a template are allowed, which is recommended minimum 1024 (Appendix B).